# User input into array. I am confused with output

Tags: c++, arrays, input

Most of the components for the array are in place.
I am however wondering what code is missing for the output to match what I am trying to do.

I tried searching for similar array coding. I would like to call the function and for the user to input numbers up to 20 different inputs.

```
 #define size 20

 using namespace std;


 int i;

 void Input(int student[]) {
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         cout << "Enter The Marks of Subject 2 of student no " << i + 1 << " ";
     cin >> student[i];
}

void display(int student[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << student[i];
}

int main() {
    int student[size];
    Input(student );
    display(student);

    return 0;
```

Comment: _"I am however wondering what code is missing for the output to match what I am trying to do."_ It's completely unclear what you're trying to do. Elaborate please.

Comment: You're missing bracket in your `for` loop in `Input`

Answer (score 2):

In your `Input` function:

```
void Input(int student[]) {
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
         cout << "Enter The Marks of Subject 2 of student no " << i + 1 << " ";
     cin >> student[i];
}
```

You not using brackets, so the `cin >> student[i];` is outside of the loop. The `i` from the `for` loop is no longer in scope, so you are using the `i` here:

```
int i;
```

Which is never given a value, which leads to undefined behavior. Add brackets:

```
void Input(int student[]) {
     for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         cout << "Enter The Marks of Subject 2 of student no " << i + 1 << " ";
         cin >> student[i];
     }
}
```

Comment: GBlodgett. It is a great response and solution. Thank you.